# SQL Injection DROP TABLE not working

Tags: mysql, sql-injection

I need to demonstrate SQL Inject using PHP/MySQL. I want to inject a DROP TABLE query in a login form but it never works. (TRUNCATE table works fine OTOH).
After I input `'; drop table users; #` as field input; query turns out to be

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email` = ''; DROP TABLE users; #' AND `password` LIKE '3232';
```

But it never works using mysql_query() function. When I copy/paste this query in PHPmyAdmin directly, it works perfectly and table gets dropped. What can be the issue?

Comment: same DB user is being used in PHP and PHPmyAdmin both with DROP previlage

Comment: Read the fine manual. mysql_query executes one statement. You have two.

Comment: How does PHPmyadmin handle such multi queries?

Comment: Presumably they read the fine manual and learned that the `mysql_*` family of functions was deprecated and used something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in php/MySQL as php does not support stacked queries. The moment you inject semicolon (;) it will fail.

You can do many other much more creative exploits using sql injection in a php-mysql application though.

1. Enumerate all databases
2. Table Names and Column Names
3. Values stored in tables
4. Upload a php backdoor

Check Out for SQL-Map as well.

Comment: Inserting a `;` is fine unless you start a new statement after it.

Answer (score 3):

MULTIPLE SQL Execution is not enabled by defaults.

So SQL Injection like `;drop table` won't work. please enable multiple sql execution. this could be enabled like http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php if you are using mysqli.

useful SQL Injection is :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users
WHERE user_id = '$user_id' AND passwd = '$passwd'
```

and user inserts `passwd` to `' || '1' = '1`.